# ajax delete after success text field should be empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this my j query code for delete request 
i want after delete text field will be empty

```
 $(document).on('click','.yes_confirm',function() {
                var relf=$(this).attr('data-rel');//alert(relf);
                if(relf != ''){ 
                var $that = $(this);
                event.preventDefault();                
                var cotext_id = $('input[id="cotext_id_'+relf+'"]').val();
                var object_id = $('input[id="object_id_'+relf+'"]').val();
                var object_origen = $('input[id="object_origen_'+relf+'"]').val();

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: $.ISA.options.base_url + "contest/admin/delete_note/",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { cotext_id: cotext_id, object_id: object_id, object_origen: object_origen },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('.popup_main').css('display','none');

                            $(this).closest('.del_edit_opt').find('input[name="name"]').val('');


                        },

                    });
                }
            });
```

this is my text field 
   " value="">

Comment: What is the issue you are facing an post your complete html to ?

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `this` in your `success` function. I guess it's not what you think it is?

Comment: `this` won't be accessible in success, instead use your defined var `$that` and also rather than setting it to `''` , `null` would be better

Comment: http://www.networkisa.org.vhost.zerolag.com/modules/contest/admin/